# What is res://*/ in .net?

Tags: .net

I came across this snippet of code on MSDN:

```
entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/AdventureWorksModel.csdl|
                            res://*/AdventureWorksModel.ssdl|
                            res://*/AdventureWorksModel.msl";
```

What does the `res://*/` mean and how does it work? I think it has to do with resource files, but I am not sure.

Google is no help because of the punctuation.

Comment: It should be noted that in this specific case, the resources pointed to are for the metadata definitions using the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea:

[res protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740.aspx)

EDIT: Incidentally, you should check [searchdotnet](http://searchdotnet.com/) for technical searches, it still uses google but filters on .net stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The 'res' protocol allows only access to unmanaged win32 resources, for managed .net assemblies use the new 'resx' protocol: [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/097794c5-6acd-4563-8237-5e385ca7e563)