# How to add an assembly manifest to a .NET executable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, manifest, fusion

How can i add an assembly manifest to my .NET executable?

---

An assembly manifest is is an XML file that is added to a .NET portable executable (PE) with resource type `RT_MANIFEST` (24).

Assembly manifests are used to declare a number of things about the executable, e.g.:

- If i want to disable DPI-scaling because i am a good developer:

  ```
  <!-- We are high-dpi aware on Windows Vista -->
  <asmv3:application xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
     <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
        <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
     </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
  ```
- i can declare that i was designed and tested on Windows 7, and i should continue to depend on any bugs in Windows 7

  ```
  <!-- We were designed and tested on Windows 7 -->
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
     <application>
        <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
     </application>
  </compatibility>
  ```
- i can declare that i am a good developer, and don't need file and registry virtualization

  ```
  <!-- Disable file and registry virtualization -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
     <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
           <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
     </security>
  </trustInfo>
  ```
- i can declare that i depend on a particular version 6 of the **Microsoft Common Controls** library:

  ```
  <!-- Dependency on Common Controls version 6 -->
  <dependency>
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
              type="win32"
              name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
              version="6.0.0.0"
              processorArchitecture="X86"
              publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
              language="*"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  ```
- i can declare that i depend on a particular version of GDI+:

  ```
  <dependency>
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86"
              publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" />
     </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  ```

---

[In the olden days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057080/vs2010-net-how-to-embed-a-resource-in-a-net-pe-executable), we would create a **resource script** file (`*.rc`), e.g.:

**wumpa.rc**

```
   1    24    AssemblyManifest.xml
```

add that file to the project, and the compiler would compile the `.rc` file; including resources in the final executable image.

Except [Visual Studio 2010 doesn't seem to have a way to add a resource script file to a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057080/vs2010-net-how-to-embed-a-resource-in-a-net-pe-executable).

How do i add a resource script to a project in Visual Studio 2010?

How do i add an assembly manifest to a project in Visual Studio 2010?

**Note**: Any solution must work in an environment with source control and multiple developers (e.g. hard-coded paths to probably not installed binaries will break the build and not work).

### Bonus Chatter

- [VS2010/.NET: How to embed a resource in a .NET PE executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057080/vs2010-net-how-to-embed-a-resource-in-a-net-pe-executable)
- VS2005: [How to embed a manifest in an assembly: let me count the ways...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cheller/archive/2006/08/24/how-to-embed-a-manifest-in-an-assembly-let-me-count-the-ways.aspx) (can't be done)

---

**Update**: Michael Fox suggests that the project properties dialog can be used to include an assembly manifest, but he doesn't indicate *where*:

[image]

---

**Update**: Things I've tried:

- From the project properties screen, select **Application**. Select radio option **Icon and Manifest**. Under **Manifest** leave the default option of `Embed manifest with default settings`:

[image]

*Doesn't work because it embeds a manifest with **default** settings, rather than my settings.*

- Under **Manifest**, change the combo option to `Create application without a manifest`:

  [image]

  *Doesn't work because it embeds no manifest*
- Under **Resources** select the **Resource File** radio option:

  [image]

  *Doesn't work because you cannot select an assembly manifest (or a resource script that includes an assembly manifest)*
- Under **Resources**, select the **Resource File** radio option, then enter the path to an assembly manifest XML file:

[image]

*Doesn't work because Visual Studio chokes when presented with an assembly manifest*:

[image]

- Under **Resources**, select the **Resource File** radio option, then enter the path to a resource script file:

[image]

*Doesn't work because Visual Studio chokes when presented with a resource script*:

[image]

- Add the `AssemblyManifest.xml` to my project, then look for it in the **Manifest** combo box:

  [image]

  *Doesn't work because the Assembly Manifest file isn't listed as an option*

> i have a dozen other things i can keep screenshotting (add a .rc file to the solution, look for it in the dropdown, select "no manifest" and change the `wumpa.rc` build action to various things, build the `.rc` file using a separate resource compiler, either manually, or a pre-build/msbuild step, and select that `.res` file as my resource). i'll stop adding extra bulk to my question and hope for an answer.

Comment: u need to add this line in manifest. <requestedexecutionlevel level="requireAdministrator" uiaccess="true"> here i am giving couple of url which may help u. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944276 http://www.professionalvisualstudio.com/blog/2007/10/05/enabling-your-application-for-uac-on-vista/

Comment: Probable duplicate of [c# - How do I create/edit a Manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to add custom information to your application's manifest, you can follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click "Add New Item".
3. Select "Application Manifest File".

This adds a file named `app.manifest` to your project, which you can open and modify as desired.

---

Similar steps, with screenshots, lifted from [Declaring Managed Applications As DPI-Aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee308410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN:

1. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on your project, point to **Add**, and then click **New Item**.
2. In the **Add New Item** dialog box, select **Application Manifest File**, and then click **Add**. The app.manifest file appears.

   [image]
3. Copy and paste the following text into the **app.manifest** file and then save.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
                   xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
                   xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

     <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>

       <!-- Disable file and registry virtualization. -->
       <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
         <security>
           <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
            <!--  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
                  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
                  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
            -->
           </requestedPrivileges>
         </security>
       </trustInfo>

       <!-- We are high-dpi aware on Windows Vista -->
       <asmv3:application xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
         <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
           <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
         </asmv3:windowsSettings>
       </asmv3:application>

       <!-- Declare that we were designed to work with Windows Vista and Windows 7-->
       <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
         <application>
           <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
           <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
           <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
         </application>
       </compatibility>

       <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
       <dependency>
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity
               type="win32"
               name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
               version="6.0.0.0"
               processorArchitecture="*"
               publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
               language="*"
           />
         </dependentAssembly>
       </dependency>

     </asmv1:assembly>
   ```
4. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the **project**, and then click **Properties** to verify that the **app.manifest** is used.

   [image]
5. Your application is now manifested as required to be "designed for Windows", and is

   - disables file and registry virtualization
   - disables DWM scaling of applications
   - announces that you were designed and tested on Windows 7 and Windows Vista
   - takes a dependency on Common Controls library version 6 (enabling the use of visual styles by the common controls)

Comment: You can also embed app.manifest this way in a Class Library project, but there's no way to confirm that this has been done because the "Manifest" field is disabled for Class Library projects. The only way to check is by viewing the project file in a text editor and look for the ApplicationManifest element in the XML. Why would you embed a manifest in a class library? One reason is for serving as a managed isolated COM server.

Comment: This works for me. but when I create the click once application deployment file, the app.manifest file is not included/considered for the App and App launches without these settings. Can anyone help me with the cause/reason for this?

Answer (score 6):

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional with Service Pack 1 installed. I am running on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. If I follow these instructions, the project properties shows **"Embed manifest with default settings"** in the resources block, and also the option is disabled! When I build, the manifest does not get embedded into the DLL as I verified by opening the DLL in resource view.

However, if I :

1. Locate the added app.manifest file in the Solution Explorer
2. Right-click and choose Properties
3. Change the Build Action property from "None" to "Embedded Resource"
4. Rebuild

The manifest file is embedded properly, which I can verify by loading the DLL into the resource view. The Manifest setting in the Application properties still shows as "Embed manifest with default settings" and is still disabled.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2008, this can be done in the Project Properties window. I'm almost positive it is the same in 2010. Right click on your project, select properties, and in the application tab you can select a manifest. You have to add it to your project first, but you can do that easily by adding an existing file.

Comment: Copied the linked screenshot into original question.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make this any clearer. It's right there in the screenshot! Under the "Icon and Manifest" radio button - "To embed a custom manifest, first add it to your project and then select it from the list below". Then there is a combo box under "Manifest" that you can use to select the manifest. To add the manifest to the project, add it just like you would any other existing file.

Comment: i've added screenshots showing why things are still unclear. Perhaps you can add some screenshots and we'll see where the missing piece is.

Comment: Cannot view image behind a corporate firewall